# Add multiple classes in if statements in React

Tags: reactjs, class

I'm trying to conditionally add a few classes in React like this....

```
<div
  className={`timesContainer ${
    index === selectedItemId && selectedItemState ? 'active' : ''
    this.checkwidth(slotRow.availableSlots) ? 'responsiveTimes' : ''
  }`}
>
```

But obviously you can't do this multiple times. Any succinct way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple `${}`s to interpolate. Make sure to put a space between the `}` and the `${` next to it.

```
<div
  className={`timesContainer ${
    index === selectedItemId && selectedItemState ? 'active' : ''
  } ${
    this.checkwidth(slotRow.availableSlots) ? 'responsiveTimes' : ''
  }`}
>
```

You also might consider defining the class name ahead of time, it might be easier to read in some situations.

```
const className = `timesContainer ${
  index === selectedItemId && selectedItemState ? 'active' : ''
} ${
  this.checkwidth(slotRow.availableSlots) ? 'responsiveTimes' : ''
}`;

// ...

<div
  className={className}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `clsx` [a light weight npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) to conditionally add multiple classnames.

Using complex ternary operators in the template literal can make your code less readable.

#### clsx Example

```
import clsx from 'clsx';

const classNames = clsx('timesContainer',{
'active': index === selectedItemId && selectedItemState,
'responsiveTimes': this.checkwidth(slotRow.availableSlots)
}

return (<div className={classNames} />
```

Comment: Here's [a blog post link](https://surajsharma.net/blog/conditionally-apply-classes-in-react) If you're interested in reading more about conditionally adding classnames in react using clsx